# How to write single line in writer file?

Tags: spring-batch

I am reading CSV file, here in each line am getting amount.

```
200,xx
300,yy
```

So finally I am calculated total amount in custom processor. I just want to print single line in text file or last line also fine, just like:

> total amount is $500

I am able to write in text but it's writing for each line, just like:

> total amount is $200
>   total amount is $500

Comment: Are you sure you need SB if you barely know it and you are in rush? Maybe a "classic" approach is more effective.

Comment: We'll probably need to see your code to be able to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you only an idea on how to proceed, but no code because the answer will be too large (usually this kind of questions are candidate for closing).

1. Read every line and convert it to a number N.
2. Don't use processor to perform calculation but use a custom writer
3. Custom writer: after every call to `write()` make sum and store partial result into step-execution context (this context is a key-value map)
4. Use a [FlatFileFooterCallback](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileFooterCallback.html) to write stored value to file

That's all.
But I have a question for you: *are you sure you need SB if you barely know it and you are in rush?*
Maybe a "classic" approach is more effective.

Comment: Thanks Luca,I am using custom writer.But not able to access values of input file.all records count printing 0.